# How to filter a generic list?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the code below which was working, but when I try to add the `Where` clause to filter the collection I get the error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension
>   method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried casting the object to `OfType<Certification>` and that failed.  I also tried casting to `IQueryable` and that failed with a similar error.  So I checked the type of my certifications variable and it is ``` "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[[GainesTrader_WCF.Certification, GainesTrader WCF," ```.  Can you see the solution to this?

```
    GainesTrader_WCF.Service1 client = new GainesTrader_WCF.Service1();
    object certifications = client.GetCertifications();
    //var filtered = certifications.OfType<Certification>().Where(o => o.CertificationAcronym == "MCSD");
    var filtered = certifications.Where(o => o.CertificationAcronym == "MCSD");
    Certifications.DataSource = filtered;
    Certifications.DataBind();
```

Comment: What type does `client.GetCertifications()` return?  The compiler error is correct - `object` does not have a `Where` method or extension method.  You need to use the proper collection type instead of `object`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with WCF?   It has nothing to do with WCF.

Comment: Tim.  I think it suggested WCF based on my variable name and I just accepted without paying close attention.  I have edited the tags to remove WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why is the certificates variable of type object? Look at the WCF proxy and verify the return type. When you set up the proxy, visual studio should've downloaded all related types.

Also, this is the first time, I've seen someone apply the Where extension method to a Object type. It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I would give the correct answer to D Stanley, but he only posted a comment.  Your comment is close to the correct answer.  I changed the variable type from object to var as he suggested and it worked.  I like it when the answer is simple.  You're right - declaring it as object doesn't make sense.  I'm still relatively new to Linq, and var is not very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast your `certifications` variable to type `IEnumerable<Certification>`:

```
var filtered = certifications
  .OfType<IEnumerable<Certification>>()
  .Where(o => o.CertificationAcronym == "MCSD");
```

or

```
 var certifications = (IEnumerable<Certification>)client.GetCertifications();
 var filtered = certifications.Where(o => o.CertificationAcronym == "MCSD");
```

Comment: I tried this and it failed because it didn't recognize .OfType (I had already tried that solution).  So a quick search said that I need an MVC version in my web.config.  This project was not MVC so it was not there.  So I added the MVC version tag in web.config and it crashed the website.  I may just leave this "as is" since it's working.  I wanted to filter out my MCAD certifications, but it's no big deal.  I don't want to spend hours debugging this.  If you see an easy fix I'll give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: `OfType` has zero to do with MVC.    The problem is that you've declared `certifications` as an `object` which does not have a `Where` method (or extension`.

Comment: D Stanley, that is the solution.  Thanks.  I changed the object type to var and it worked.